# Error after code completion

Tags: arcpy

Why arcpy throwing an error after completed code execution ?

```
import os
import arcpy
import xlrd

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

inWS = r'C:\Excel'
excelDirectoryName = inWS
arcpy.env.workspace = inWS
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Current")

workspaces = arcpy.ListWorkspaces()
for ws in workspaces:
    arcpy.AddError(ws)

del mxd, workspaces
```

[image: output]

output :

```
Executing: Script
Start Time: Fri Nov 29 17:52:47 2013
Running script Script...
C:\Excel\Attribute Update sheet.xls
C:\Excel\Book1.xls
Completed script Script...
Failed to execute (Script).
Failed at Fri Nov 29 17:52:51 2013 (Elapsed Time: 4.00 seconds)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's throwing an error because you told it to with `arcpy.AddError(ws)`.

If you simply wanted to print out the value of ws you could use `arcpy.AddMessage(ws)` instead. Whenever you use `arcpy.AddError` it prints the message as an error and signals ArcGIS that your script had an error and didn't complete properly.

Comment: Thanks, after change the code as you suggested the error is not appear.